# Why does my JQuery .after() inserts code before the element?

Tags: jquery

I got this:

```
               $('input[name=whatWeLove1]').before('<ul><li>');
               $('input[name=whatWeLove1]').after('</li></ul>');
```

and it generates this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="whatWeLove1" class="" maxlength="40">
```

Why?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: The fundamental point here is that you're thinking in terms of HTML markup, but you're not dealing with markup once the page is loaded, you're dealing with the DOM tree -- actual objects in an actual object graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because you're inputting broken code (before you fix it)... so the browser (or possibly firebug or possibly jquery) is trying to display it as properly formatted/fixed.

The best way to achieve what you're trying to do is to use `.wrap()`

`$('input[name=whatWeLove1]').wrap('<ul><li>');`

Comment: You don't need the close tags.

Answer (score 3):

Because jQuery will automatically assume you don't want to just insert opening tags and close the element for you.

You want to use `.wrap();`

```
  $('input[name=whatWeLove1]').wrap('<ul><li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery manipulates the DOM, not the HTML. It's a subtle distinction, but it means it won't let you produce invalid HTML. Running the first line produces unmatched tags until you run the second line, and it won't let you do that

You need to use the `wrap` function, as @NicolaPeluchetti describes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$('input[name=whatWeLove1]').wrap('<ul>').wrap('<li >');
```

Comment: Beat me to it. But you only need the one wrap function.

Answer (score 1):

because you insert the element before:

```
 $('input[name=whatWeLove1]').before('<ul><li>');
```

This auto-closes the element before your input element, to prevent faulty markup.

YOu can either create the `<ul><li>` structure and insert your input afterwards or `wrap()` the input directly.